# Select row after filter row has a coincident column in sql

Tags: sql

I have a database as below

```
Column1 column2 column3    
A123           abc          Def    
A123           xyz           Abc    
B456           Gh            Ui
```

I want to select rows which don't have coincident content in column 1 by sql command.

In this case, The expected result is only row 3rd.
How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: WITH CTE AS (Select COUNT(Column1) OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ) as coincident )Select * from CTE where coincident =1

Answer (score 1):

you could use a join with a subselect for count =1

```
select * from my_table m
inner join (
  select column1, count(*)
  from my_table 
  group by column_1 
  having count(*) =1
) t on  t.column_1 = m.column_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (Select COUNT(Column1) OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ) as coincident,* from table )Select * from CTE where coincident =1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select Column1, column2, column3 
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by column1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

However, there are other fun ways.  For instance, aggregation:

```
select column1, max(column2) as column2, max(column3) as column3
from t
group by column1
having count(*) = 1;
```

Or if you know one of the other columns is going to have different values on different rows, then `not exists` may be the most efficient solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.column1 = t.column1 and
                        t2.column2 <> t.column2
                 );
```